# how to check if a None is not passed as an argument where a pandas dataframe is expected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a function which looks like below.

```
def some_func(df:pd.Dataframe=pd.Dataframe()):
  if not df or df.empty:
    //some dataframe operations
```

I want to ensure that someone hasn't called the above function with : `some_func(None)`.

But with the above check, I get `ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous.`

How do I ensure that I do a `None` check before starting dataframe operations ?

Comment: `df:pd.Dataframe=pd.Dataframe()` basically means you are initializing a `df` and passing it as input if the user does not pass that argument. So, that makes it an optional input. In your case, `df.empty` check will suffice, you don't need the `not df` part

Comment: Alternatively, I would check for the type of the param passed and fail if is not pandas dataframe

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan still a None can be passed as arg to the function.

Comment: @Naxi do a `if isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame)`

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the argument is `None` like so:

```
def some_func(df:pd.Dataframe=pd.Dataframe()):
  if df is None:
    # some dataframe operations
```